# How to Re-Wire Switch to make the Connected Outlet Permanently Hot

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

I have a light switch that controls an outdoor light and bottom wall outlet simultaneously. We live in the Northern Virginia area. Per the diagram below, I would like to have the switch only control the outdoor light while leaving the wall outlet permanently hot. I have included pictures of the wiring at the switch and the outlet. Please advise.

**Diagram**

[image]

**Switch Wiring**

[image]

**Outlet Wiring**

[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: Apologies, just re-uploaded with bigger pictures. Hopefully it is a lot clearer now. We are located in Northern Virginia, USA.

Comment: Hmm, that switched red wire is setting of alarms. Light switches should only be all hot so they really should be the same color, so something weird is happening, but I'll need to let someone more familiar with NA electrical codes to confirm. Normally it would've been really easy to just grab the outlet's wire and just pigtail it, bypassing the switch, but I just don't know why that red wire is there.

Comment: That outlet might need to remain switched if there are no ceiling lights in the room with their own switches.  @Nelson  is right that red is odd.  There looks to be only two whites(neutral?) in the box, so that red should stay in the cable except in a box, not be separated.

Comment: In addition to the other three-way switch we also need clear pictures of all the wires inside both the switch boxes, clearly showing which wires belong to which cables and what their colors are.  The objective is to determine if the outlet and light are *both* cabled into one of the switch boxes, or if the cabling is from one to the other.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a 3-way switch. The top black looks like it’s back-stabbed and in parallel with the red wire. I’m guessing  that’ll the black runs to the outlet and the black runs to the light.

Comment: @RehanSyed Can you please take another photo(a) showing the switch from the other side or from the back and the switch box showing the cables  in the back?

Comment: A picture of the wiring at the light would be very informative

Answer (score 2):

You need to determine which of the 3 wires at the switch are hot from the breaker box. ( I assume it is the one at the bottom of the pic)

Then determine which wire goes to the outlet, ( Of the red or black, my inclination is the black)

Connect the constant hot and the wire to the outlet. Add a pigtail wire that will go to the switch. (This gets you constant hot to the outlet.)

Connect the pigtailed wire and the remaining wire to the switch. ( This makes the light switched)

Now that you know how to do this, remember as noted by crip659, if you do not have a switched light or outlet in the room, you have violated that NEC requirement.

Comment: I did have a comment about pigtailling, but @Nelson does have a point about the red.  How does the red go to the light, if the black goes to the outlet?  Another black and white cable without the red and it would be simple pigtail.

Comment: @crip659, The power could come from the light box, into the switch box. Black is hot, red goes back to the light.  Another cable carries hot to the outlet and neutral. The 2 neutrals are tied together as seen in the pic.   It may be unconventional, but not a code violation.

Comment: That would work. A new normal switch loop with the added outlet.  It is different way of thinking and makes everything simple.  Now if OP has another light, this will be the correct answer.